# Winforms: Errors when running oledb connection (installable Isam, Commandtext was not set for the command object)

Tags: c#, winforms, ms-access, oledb

My situation is once I press button, the code will retrieve the `EquipmentBrand` and `EquipmentType` from MS Access with respect to the `SerialNumber`. I am able to retrieve the serial number through the class `oledb` and made it auto complete. However, now I am having issue retrieving equipment brand and type. I have tried two codes but both have different errors.Here is my access screenshot: [MS Access screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9q3Qv.png)

For first error, I have changed my platform to x86.

**First error: Could not find installable Isam** at line `connection.Open();`

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        oledb da = new oledb();
        textBox1.AutoCompleteMode = AutoCompleteMode.SuggestAppend;
        textBox1.AutoCompleteSource = AutoCompleteSource.CustomSource;
        textBox1.AutoCompleteCustomSource = da.Loadserialnum();
    }

private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var connection = new OleDbConnection("Provider = Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source = C:\\Users\\equipment.accdb");
        var command = connection.CreateCommand();
        {
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("SerialNumber", (textBox1.Text));
            connection.Open(); //error here
            var reader = command.ExecuteReader();
            while (reader.Read())
            {
                textBox2.Text = reader["EquipmentBrand"].ToString();
                textBox3.Text = reader["EquipmentType"].ToString();
            }
        }
    }
```

For second error, Ive changed `Data Source` (another way that works for other who had my 1st problem), but a new error occurs: **Command text was not set for command object** at line `command.ExecuteReader`

Hope to get some help thanks!

Comment: You should not use textbox1.Text as this will allow SQL Injection attacks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since [`OleDbConnection.CreateCommand()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.oledb.oledbconnection.createcommand?view=netframework-4.7.2) returns an instance of `OleDbCommand`, you need to set [`CommandText`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.oledb.oledbcommand.commandtext?view=netframework-4.7.2) property to a query string you want to execute before opening the connection, otherwise it will throw *Command text was not set for command object* error. Below is an example to use `CommandText` property:

```
private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var connection = new OleDbConnection("Provider = Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source = C:\\Users\\equipment.accdb");
    var command = connection.CreateCommand();

    // query string example
    command.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM TableName WHERE SerialNumber = ?"; 

    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("SerialNumber", (textBox1.Text));
    connection.Open(); // open the connection
    var reader = command.ExecuteReader();
    while (reader.Read())
    {
        textBox2.Text = reader["EquipmentBrand"].ToString();
        textBox3.Text = reader["EquipmentType"].ToString();
    }
}
```

Comment: OLEDB parameters are positional not named. So this will work but if you have more than one parameters they must be added in the order they occur in the SQL. To make this clear you could say command.Parameters.AddWithValue("?", (textBox1.Text));

Comment: Thanks for the replies. I've added the command text and it worked. I will take note of the SQL injections risk and improve accordingly. May I know what are the options to be used beside the usage of `textBox1.Text`?